# C# Date Conversion Issue when complete year is unknown or not specified

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, type-conversion

We are storing only 4 digits in the database for the date of birth field . For example , if the date of birth is  05 Aug 1991 it gets stored as 050891

The issue here is when we do below :

```
Convert.ToDateTime("05/08/28") -> it produces 05 08 2029

Convert.ToDateTime("05/08/30") -> it produces 05 08 1930
```

Can some one please help me understand why first date year is considered as 2029 and in the second case it is 1930 instead of 2030 .

How .Net determines the year ?

Here is the .Net fiddle demonstrating the results

[image: Fiddler]

Comment: Always store dates in a database in `date` or `datetime` format, not `int` or `varchar`, then you won't have these problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 1st .NET example, you wrote `05/08/29` so year `2029` is ok.

The 2-digit year is translated to a 4-digit year using [Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Globalization_Calendar_TwoDigitYearMax) property.